# How do I implement a system where I can drag the world around?

Tags: java

I am making a game (sort of CityVille-based) where you are looking down on a city from above. I want to make it so that I can drag the world around to look at different parts of the map.

Here is my code:

```
package com.cgp.buildtown;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable, MouseMotionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BufferedImage banner;
    private String chars = " `~1!2@3#4$5%6^7&8*9(0)-_=+qQwWeErRtTyYuUiIoOpP[{]}\\|aAsSdDfFgGhHjJkKlL;:'\"zZxXcCvVbBnNmM,<.>/?";
    public String cityName;
    private int[] offset;
    public Thread thread;
    private int totalOffset = 0;
    private boolean[][] townAreas = new boolean[15][15];

    public Game() {
        super();
        setBackground(new Color(69, 139, 0));
        loadImages();
        townAreas[8][8] = true;
        townAreas[0][1] = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        thread = new Thread(this);
    }

    void findOffset() {
        offset = new int[cityName.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < cityName.length(); i++) {
            int ch = chars.indexOf(cityName.charAt(i));
            if (ch < 0)
                continue;
            if (isShort(ch)) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < offset.length; j++) {
                    offset[j] += 25;
                }
                totalOffset += 25;
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isShort(int ch) {
        if (ch == 0 || ch == 1 || ch == 4 || ch == 14 || ch == 20 || ch == 22 || ch == 41 || ch == 42 || ch == 47 || ch == 48 || ch == 49 || ch == 50 || ch == 51 || ch == 52 || ch == 65 || ch == 69 || ch == 71 || ch == 72 || ch == 73 || ch == 74 || ch == 89 || ch == 91 || ch == 93)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private void loadImages() {
        try {
            banner = ImageIO.read(new File("res/banner.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(118, 238, 0));

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                if (townAreas[i][j]) {
                    g.fillRect(j * 400, i * 400, 400, 400);
                }
            }
        }

        int length = (cityName.length() * 45) - totalOffset;
        int x = 400 - (length / 2);
        for (int k = 0; k < cityName.length(); k++) {
            int ch = chars.indexOf(cityName.charAt(k));
            if (ch < 0)
                continue;
            g.drawImage(banner, (x + (k * 45)) - offset[k], 0, ((x + (k * 45)) + 45) - offset[k], 45, ch * 45, 0, (ch * 45) + 45, 45, null);
        }
        g.drawImage(banner, x - 15, 0, x, 45, 4276, 0, 4290, 45, null);
        g.drawImage(banner, x + length, 0, x + length + 15, 45, 4291, 0, 4305, 45, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a specific question.  Which part of this, specifically, are you having trouble with?

Comment: Putting a system in place where I can drag the world around (i.e. MouseMotionListeners). I have tried different ways to do it, but none of them are successful.

Comment: maybe try that code review stack exchange site..or try specific question.

Comment: That's still not specific.  Is it capturing mouse events that's the problem?  Or is it converting the mouse events into the required coordinate transforms?  Or is it updating the display?  Or is it something else?

Comment: I don't know how to do the calculations in order to create that "slippy map" effect.

Comment: It is converting the mouse events into the required coordinate transforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the terminology for the effect you want is called "slippy map". This is the same sort of user experience you see in Google Maps.

There are plenty of examples of doing this sort of thing in a web browser, there are even some JQuery plugins. Doing it within Java2D - you'd need to Google around.

We'd need much more specific information for people to help beyond stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Ok, I'll start looking around for that. That's exactly what I want.